How can I implement a D-Pad movement for console?
I'm making a 2.5D obby and I want to implement D-Pad movement because most people with thumb sticks have stick drift and so I wanted a way for them to play without worrying about uncontrollable movement. I don’t know the right script for it though.
So I placed this script as a Local a script and put it into the StarterPlayerScripts:
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer


local function onInput(input, gameProcessed)
    if gameProcessed then
        return
    end

    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Gamepad1 then
        if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.DPadUp then
            
            print("DPAD Up Pressed")
            
            player.Character:Move(Vector3.new(0, 0, -1))
        elseif input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.DPadDown then
           
            print("DPAD Down Pressed")
            
            player.Character:Move(Vector3.new(0, 0, 1))
        elseif input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.DPadLeft then
            
            print("DPAD Left Pressed")

            player.Character:Move(Vector3.new(-1, 0, 0))
        elseif input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.DPadRight then
           
            print("DPAD Right Pressed")
            
            player.Character:Move(Vector3.new(1, 0, 0))
        end
    end
end

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(onInput)

